# A SQL join with a group by and having clause not producing desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have these four tables:

```
Store (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    name varchar
)

Products (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    storeID uniqueidentifier,
    productname varchar
)

Customer (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    storeID uniqueidentifier,
    fName,
    lName,
    email
)

orders (
    row bigint,
    id uniqueidentifier,
    store_ID uniqueidentifier,
    cust_id uniqueidentifier,
    prod_id uniqueidentifier,
    date datetime
)
```

We are designing a query that will find all customers that have from 110 to 250 orders from a particular store?

We are trying to list the customer name, store name, and the number of orders from that customer from a particular store.

The query we have tried is:

```
select c.firstname + ' '+c.LastName, c.EmailAddress, s.name,  COUNT(o.id) from Orders o 
    inner join store s on s.ID=o.store_ID 
            inner join Customers c on c.ID=o.cust_ID 
    group by (c.firstname + ' '+c.LastName+cast(o.cust_ID as varchar(max) ))
    having count(o.id) >110 and count(o.id)<250
```

But we get errors from the join statement above. Any idea on what we are doing incorrectly?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply listing the non-aggregate columns in the group by:

```
select
    c.firstname + ' ' + c.LastName,
    c.EmailAddress,
    s.name,
    count(o.id)
from Orders o
inner join store s on s.ID=o.store_ID
inner join Customers c on c.ID=o.cust_ID
group by c.firstname + ' ' + c.LastName,
    c.EmailAddress,
    s.name
having count(o.id) between 111 and 249
```

Note also the simplification by using `between` for the `having` condition, albeit with a modification of the range values because `between` is inclusive.

Comment: Thanks you Bohemian!!! I was having difficulty understanding that group by you can list multiple items with a comma... cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not grouping by all the columns in your select statement:

```
select c.firstname + ' '+c.LastName, c.EmailAddress, s.name,  COUNT(o.id) from Orders o 
    inner join store s on s.ID=o.store_ID 
            inner join Customers c on c.ID=o.cust_ID 
    group by c.firstname + ' '+c.LastName, c.EmailAddress, s.name
    having count(o.id) >110 and count(o.id)<250
```